# strange behaviour of initialised input

Tags: html, angularjs, input

I have a table of ratios . One of the columns is a button. When I click on it the details of the row will be shown and I can modify some fields. So I used Initialised input . However when I modify the text in the input , the original text is modified too and I didn't understand why .

**Part of the code of the table:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="ratio in listRatios ">
    <td>{{ratio.name}}</td>
    <td ><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
         ng- click="showDetail(ratio)">D&eacutetail</button></td>                           
</tr>
```

**input and test**

```
<label>Nom: <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="modif.name" /></label>        
        <div>{{modif.name}}</div>
        <div>{{original.name}}</div>
```

**my controller**

```
angular.module('app').controller('RatioCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {    
    $scope.listRatios=[];
    $scope.original=null;
    $scope.modif=null;  
    $scope.detail=false;
    $scope.form=null;

    $scope.getRatiosList = function() {  
        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'getRatio.web'}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.listRatios = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
        });
    }

        $scope.showDetail = function(ratio){
        $scope.original= ratio;
        $scope.modif= ratio;
        $scope.detail=true;
    }
});
```

my problem is that when I modify the value in the input (**modif**) the value of **original** and the **value of the row** in the table change too . 
how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's expected. `ratio`, in the table, and `modif`, in the detail form, both reference the exact same object. So, if you modify `modif.name`, you also modify `ratio.name`, and the table is thus updated. That's the basic principle of two-way binding in angular:

```
var ratio = {
    name: 'foo'
};
var modif = ratio;
modif.name = 'bar';
console.log(ratio.name); // prints 'bar'
```

If you want the detail form to modify another object, then you need to make a copy of `ratio`, and make `modif` reference that copy. When you "save" the form, you will then have to copy all the fields of `modif` to `ratio`, or to replace the old `ratio` by `modif`.

Comment: ok , I've replaced $scope.modif= ratio; with angular.copy(ratio, $scope.modif); . now  Only modif is modified . thanks

Answer (score 0):

i belive tath you in some part of code say tat `modif = origin`.

in that part you shold to clone origin.

try this

```
// Deep copy
 modif = jQuery.extend(true, {}, origin);
```

Answer (score 0):

$scope.original= ratio;
  $scope.modif= ratio;

both variable referring to same object that's why this is happening.

Try this
$scope.original= jQuery.extend(true, {}, ratio);
$scope.modif= jQuery.extend(true, {}, ratio);